# Prove that the polynomials $1,\alpha-t,(\alpha-t)^2,...,(\alpha-t)^n$ generate the P_n(t) space of polynomials degree $\le n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Prove that the polynomials $\alpha,\alpha-t,(\alpha-t)^2,...,(\alpha-t)^n$ generate the P_n(t) space of polynomials degree $\le n$. Find the coordinates of an arbitrary polynomial p_n(t) of degree $\le n$ in this basis.

Let $\{e_i\}$ be the basis: $1,\alpha-t,...,(\alpha-t)^n$, and $\{e_i'\}: 1,t,...,t^n$.

I found the transition matrix from $\{e_i\}$ to $\{e_i'\}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 &\alpha &\alpha^2 &\dots &(-1)^0\binom{n}{0}\alpha^n\\0 &-1 &-2\alpha &\dots &(-1)^1\binom{n}{1}\alpha^{n-1}\\0 &0 &1 &\dots &(-1)^2\binom{n}{2}\alpha^{n-2}\\ \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\0 &0 &0 &\dots &(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}\alpha^0\end{pmatrix}
$$

This proves that $\{e_i\}$ is a basis, since we know that $\{e_i'\}$ is a basis.

I've been stuck at the second part of the problem and don't know how to approach it. I'd be very grateful if you could help me out.

Edit: Fixed an error in the problem statement.

Comment: What is $\alpha$? If you found the transformation matrix, what is left to be done?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I'll fix it now

Comment: Don't I need to find the inverse of that matrix?

Comment: @SofiaB.Lopez You only need to know that an inverse exists, which is easy to see since the matrix is trianglar and and has determinant equal to the product of diagonals: $ \pm 1 $. (In fact, you don't even need to know the upper triangle to know this, you just need to know that the matrix _is_ triangular with no zeros on the diagonal).

Comment: First of all, why do you write $\{e_i\}$? We denote sets with big letters and this looks like a singletone. Then, what's the puropse of the subscript $i$ . You can prove that no polynomial in the basis can be written as a linear combination of the predecessors.

Comment: I've seen my professors write $\{e_i\}$ to denote a basis, as an abbreviation to $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p(t)=\sum a_jt^{j}$ then $p(t)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} a_j[\alpha-(\alpha-t)]^{j}$. By Binomial Theorem we get $p(t)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} a_j \sum\limits_{k=0}^{j}\binom {j} {k}(-1)^{k}(\alpha-t)^{k}\alpha ^{j-k}$. Hence $p(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} b_k(\alpha-t)^{k}$ where $b_k=\sum\limits_{j=k}^{n}\binom {j} {k} (-1)^{k} a_j \alpha ^{j-k}$.